# Protonmail custom domain not receiving icloud mail

Tags: email-server, cloudflare

I am trying to setup Protonmail with my custom domain (thekeenprogrammer.com)

The problem is, I can only seem to receive mail from my gmail account and not iCloud. What could be causing the issue and how could I fix it?

If it helps, here is my spf1 dns settings:

#### Config One:

v=spf1 include:_spf.protonmail.ch imap.mail.me.com  smtp.mail.me.com mx ~all

#### Config Two

v=spf1 include:_spf.protonmail.ch mx ~all

Both the first and second configuration only allows emails from my gmail account to be received by thekeenprogrammer.com. thekeenprogrammer.com cannot receive email from my iCloud account for some reason. I have also checked inbox, archive, trash and spam folders and my iCloud emails are not there either.

What do I need to do to fix this issue?

### Edit 1

Here is my mx configuration:
Name = @
Server = mail.protonmail.ch
Priority = 10

## Edit 2

I have also tried to send an email using telnet, however I get a timeout exceeded error. Here are the commands.

[image]

Comment: SPF records are for sending mail. You need to check MX records, which are for receiving mail.

Comment: @MichaelHampton updated with my MX configuration.

Comment: That seems reasonable. You probably need to [disclose the actual domain name](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632) at this point.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Why do I need to? That post says I can as long as I’m allowed to use that domain which example.com allows everyone to use it.

Comment: Because it's very unlikely that you will ever get an answer which solves your problem without doing so.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Why would that make a difference? I don’t have a website at the moment on it and just using it for protonmail at the moment. I don’t want to make the domain public knowledge at the moment unless I have to. Also stops people spamming my emails.

Comment: Because if that really is your MX record, something else is terribly broken with your domain. You can try using online tools like intodns or mxtoolbox to diagnose the problem, and you might even get lucky and find it. But someone who's been doing this for years can probably find the issue in moments. BTW, not publishing your domain anywhere doesn't prevent spam. Domain registrations are [public knowledge](https://domainpunch.com/tlds/daily.php).

Comment: @MichaelHampton Added my domain.

Comment: I'm pretty convinced this is Protonmail's fault. Your DNS records are certainly correct. Attempting to send an email to anything at your domain gives me the bizarre error `550 5.5.1 Protocol error`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Hmm. Strange. Did you try sending those emails from gmail or another service?

Comment: Nope, I just did straight SMTP. You should get hold of Protonmail at this point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75771/discussion-between-iprogram-and-michael-hampton).

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thats strange, I get connection timeout. Did I do a wrong command?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Peotonmail say that error is part of a bounce-back mail. Probably because you didn’t send it to a valid email account. If t helps, I’ll setup a test email account to send mail to.